# Sending Email in Flutter Web without a Backend

Tags: flutter, email, mail-sender

I'm working on a Flutter web application and need to implement email sending functionality directly from the client side without using a backend server. I don't have a backend and would like to explore options within Flutter web itself.

I've looked into mailer library, but I'm unsure about the best way to achieve this without compromising security.

Specific Questions:

Is it possible to send emails directly from a Flutter web app without a backend?
Are there any Flutter packages or client-side libraries that support email sending for web applications?
Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like what @randal and @faBotch said there is no way to send an email from frontend without using backend
that is why i used this function:

```
void sendEmail(
    {required String email,
    required String subject,
    required String name,
    required String body}) async {
  String encodedSubject = Uri.encodeComponent(subject);
  String encodedBody = Uri.encodeComponent(body);
  String mailtoLink =
      'mailto:$email?subject=$encodedSubject&body=$encodedBody&headers=header1:$name';

  if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(mailtoLink))) {
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(mailtoLink));
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $mailtoLink';
  }
}
```

and it is open the Mail application.

Answer (score 0):

You will be unable to send directly from your mobile phone to any arbitrary mail server because of all the necessary spam blocking setups.  You'll have to go through a trusted relay of some kind.  And to use the user's mail credentials, the best you can do is open a 'mailto' URL.

So your choices are: use a mail service, or open a mailto.  That's about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested on web but it may works with the package [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

You can try

```
final emailUri = Uri.parse('mailto:$EMAIL?subject=$emailSubject');
await launchUrl(emailUri);
```

On mobile side, it launches the default mail app but I don't know what happens on web

Comment: it is correct if I want to open mail app, but I want to send an email without open another app, I want it from my flutter web app.